# Unable to write in first line of csv file

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, csv, file-writing

I'm trying to append values to a csv file and convert it into a list. However, I'm not able to write on the first line of the csv file. Instead, the code starts writing from the second line. Any clarifications would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
        time = get_time()
        time_list = []
        with open('time_data.csv', 'a', newline= '') as time_file:
            time_file_write = csv.writer(time_file, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            time_file_write.writerow([time])
        with open('time_data.csv', 'r') as time_data:
                read = csv.reader(time_data)
                for i in read:
                    time_list.append(int(i[0]))
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the mode to "w" from "a" while writing?

Comment: Doesn't that overwrite the value? I want to keep appending values every time I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not reproduceble.  But...

A CRLF before the first line and **no** CRLF after the last line is what Windows CSV would have (older versions). New versions of Windows would keep the first line perfectly and add an additional CRLF after the last line. In Linux there will be no unwanted CRLF anywhere. Even if you re-define under write, etc, the basic behavior remains.

**Few points to note**:

- The **csv writerow** takes different settings for Windows / Linux / etc as given under lib/csv.py. The settings are different for different versions of Windows. But it is the same for all flavors / versions of Linux. So, though the error does not show up **in Windows** here, you might have...
- While asking...better if you furnish here a simple, to the point and very immediately executable code. Like...

```
    import csv
    
    time = '12'
    with open('time_data.csv', 'a', newline= '') as time_file:
      time_file_write = csv.writer(time_file, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
      time_file_write.writerow([time])
    with open('time_data.csv', 'r') as time_data:
      read = csv.reader(time_data)
      for i in read:
        print(i)
```

This code - after eliminating (1) the get_time() and (2) defining / populating the time_list - would make you understand where the issue is. And it ran as expected.

- Considering the fact that this code (without `get_time()`) does not generate blank first line in Windows too and since the Code line  `time = get_time()` adds ambiguity as we do not know what it returns to `time`, you need to check that too to resolve - if older Windows Version is not the case.